# How do I receive QList<QVariantMap> over dbus in qt 4.8?

Tags: qt, qt4

I have C++ code that communicates with another process which returns a list of string->variant mappings, in other words a `QList<QVariantMap>`. In QT5 I can demarshall `QDbusArgument reply` as follows:

```
    QList<QVariantMap> replyMap = qdbus_cast<QList<QVariantMap>>(reply.arguments().first());
```

This doesn't work with QT4.8. I suspect I need the correct invocation of `qDbusRegisterMetaType`, but try as I might, I cannot figure out the magic combination. The compiler responds:

```
..../include/QtCore/qmetatype.h:169:79: error: ‘qt_metatype_id’ is not a member of ‘QMetaTypeId<QList<QMap<QString, QVariant> > >’
```

Unfortunately our code base is stuck on QT4.8 for now, so an upgrade to QT5 is not possible.

How do I do the same thing in qt4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague helped me out. The answer is to put this in a header file somewhere.

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (QList<QVariantMap>);
```